# Javascript performance, recreate function or bind then?

Tags: javascript, performance, callback, closures, bind

My application is a local server that receive about **2/3 requests per seconds**.

At each request, it stores and update data, process some calculation, update view (react), ...

I would like to know **what is faster**, when i have to use closures :

- Simply create the function where I need it:

  `var parentValue = 'ok';`

  `randomAsyncFunction(function() {
     console.log(parentValue);
   }`
- Create a "global" function and then bind the callback with needed values:

  `function testCallback(value) {
     console.log(value);
   }`

  `var parentValue = 'ok';
   randomAsyncFunction(testCallback.bind(undefined, parentValue));`

**Note:** theses pseudo-codes will be executed 2/3 times per seconds. For the second example, the `testCallback` function will be created once, and the bind will be called instead of re-creating the function.

So, is it better or worse to use the second example ?

Comment: 23 requests per second? That's nothing. You should not need to care about performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `bind` and the closure function expression do create a new function object. Their difference in performance will be negligible. If you really care enough, run a benchmark with your actual code and real data to see which solution is faster.

In your case, you should only care which solution is more readable and maintainable. None is strictly better or worse than the other, you have to decide yourself which one you like better.